# How to pull all CSS rules on an element together

Tags: css, frontend, jsfiddle

For using a site like jsfiddle or cssdesk, how would I pull all the css rules that apply to my element together in one place? My CMS has a pretty large number of CSS files that act on the same elements.

Comment: I usually do that through the element inspector that comes with Chrome (or Firefox).

Comment: I use the built-in Firefox inspector. Can it be used to grab all the rules at once and copy/paste them?

Comment: I think you should be more specific about the exact problem you are trying to solve. Usually one does not post an entire site to JSFiddle

Comment: I'm more used with the one in Chrome, but I think you can do that in the Firefox inspector by clicking on the "Computed" button.

Comment: @ScottSimpson I'm not posting an entire site. I just want to post a snippet of HTML and make sure that I'm getting ALL the style rules that apply to that element, including inherited styles.

Comment: Seriously? Three downvotes with no comments about why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firefox's built-in inspector (not firebug) to inspect the element. In the column that pops up for the inspector, choose "Computed" tab.

Highlight all the styles you want, then right click and choose, Copy Selection.

Go to your jsFiddle or CSSDeck, paste in the properties, and surround it with your rule:

h1 {
... your copied stuff here ...
}

NOTE: you'll need to add semicolons to the end of all the properties.

Comment: For some reason I didn't believe it could be this simple. Durr! Thank you for helping me see the obvious thing that I was overlooking.

Comment: You're welcome. Thank mdepolli, too. He got us half the way there with the "Computed" tab.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understanding the question properly, but I think you're asking how to apply all the same styles on a fiddle that are applied on your own site. If that's the case, then on jsFiddle, in the left nav, there is an Add Resources option. If your site is public, then you can enter in the direct url to your css file(s) there.

Then any html you enter in the fiddle should get the styles from those css files applied in the result when you run it.

Comment: That's very useful to know, but unfortunately this site is on my laptop, not a public server.

Answer (score 0):

Two answers spring to mind:

1. The first is simply to upload your CSS files from your laptop to a server somewhere. You could also run a webserver from your laptop if you can open port 80 from your router to your local computer. You could get a static URL to your IP address from a service like [No-IP Free](http://www.no-ip.com/personal/).
2. Use a CSS pre-processor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) when composing your CSS on your computer. This requires a bit of a change to your workflow, but you will find the changes make life as a web developer much easier in the long run. Both SASS and LESS understand vanilla CSS, so you don't have to change your existing files, just the extensions. They also both have the ability to import other SASS or LESS files on your computer, and include them in the output generated CSS. So, using SASS for an example… if your main CSS file is called `screen.css`, move it to `screen.scss`. The SASS pre-processor will read through and render the file back to CSS after you make changes. Now, to include another file in your `screen.scss` file, add `@import 'newFile.scss';` and the CSS file SASS generates will include both `screen.scss` and `newFile.scss`.

   Following this design paradigm has the additional benefit of keeping all your CSS in one output file. It is recommended that you keep all your CSS in one file to minimize server requests (see [Should I still bother keeping all css in one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047507/should-i-still-bother-keeping-all-css-in-one-file) for discussion).