# Multiple CSS files vs combined file

Tags: css, performance, pagespeed

So everyone knows the pros of having a single CSS file for a webpage.

- Only one HTTP request is needed to fetch it
- Once stored in cache, all webpages using it will be blessed

But I think there's a great pro of having multiple CSS files

- All CSS files will be downloaded parallely, thus less time...

So If I have 500KB of code of CSS and internet speed of 50KBps (yes, i live in a poor country :-/ )...

```
method A will take (10+x)secs     # where x is the time for HTTP request
method B should take (1+x)secs    # if I divide it into 10 files
```

Am I wrong, If I say "Method B is much better" ?

Comment: Every HTTP request has extra padding, (headers etc.) that adds to the size of the page. Since css files tend to be small, the more files there are the larger % of the entire download is padding. So, there is a trade-off and it is not so easy to tell which will be better, you will have to test. More important is browser caching, so the files don't need to be fetched every page load.

Comment: With method B, you take 1*n+m units of time, where n and m are unknown, and they both depend on the number of connections to the server. Browsers have also a limit of concurrent connections to domains, be it 4 or 8. By using that many connections instead of one, you have to wait for a free connection slot before downloading your next resource (image, font or javascript)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend that you use a CSS Minifier, like http://cssminifier.com/.

Regarding your speed test, in your case maybe is really faster to use multiple files, but try it and test your page at [Google's PageSpeed Insights](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

Specially if your target is your own country, and if you know that the internet is slow all over there.

Answer (score 0):

From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047507/should-i-still-bother-keeping-all-css-in-one-file)

> It's not about bandwidth speed but number of http requests, this makes
>   a lot of sense for a mobile connection.
>
> However the approach of having different css files to keep the project
>   modular is solid, as it helps you keeping your css organized the way
>   you want it without having all the code in one file only. Then you can
>   benefit of css preprocessors / minifiers to concatenate and compress
>   all your css files in a single one for production